# Google Cloud Java Speech Recognition gRPC Example Fails with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, grpc

So, I downloaded the Google Cloud [Java samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/grpc) and tried to run a jar with the streaming example. To do this I modified pom.xml by adding the main class tag under the end of the  tag that had the jar-with-dependencies descriptor tag.

```
<archive>
    <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          <mainClass>com.examples.cloud.speech.StreamingRecognizeClient</mainClass>
    </manifest>
</archive>
```

The problem is that I get this error when trying to run the packaged jar, mvn compile and package work just fine, but running this command fails.

I've checked the grpc package, maxInboundMessageSize() is right in AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder which NettyChannelBuilder extends. The example works just fine when I run it from Intellij.

```
java -jar grpc-sample-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar                                                                                                                                                                            master
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.maxInboundMessageSize()I
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:263)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:239)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:69)
        at com.examples.cloud.speech.StreamingRecognizeClient.createChannel(StreamingRecognizeClient.java:109)
        at com.examples.cloud.speech.StreamingRecognizeClient.main(StreamingRecognizeClient.java:282)
```

Same thing happens when I leave pom.xml unchanged and instead run:

```
java -cp target/grpc-sample-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.examples.cloud.speech.StreamingRecognizeClient
```

I'd also like to know why my other packaging options are with Maven, I've never worked with it before and I'm pretty sure I messed up something.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like some wrong version of netty grpc of the dependency is used. May be [worth reporting a bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues).

Comment: Yes, it does look like a bug, I was hoping that maybe I did something wrong and there would be a fix for that.

Comment: I've rolled back all the grpc artifacts to 1.0.3 from 1.1.2.  Should work now -- sorry for the problem.  (the bot is supposed to test these things before updating)

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel the pom is still trying to use 1.1.2 and the issue persists. Please merge in the change.

Comment: Sigh - the bot that updates sometimes is a bit more aggressive than it should be.  Rolled back to 1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I have done a fresh git clone and I am getting the same problem.

This is what I am doing:

```
git clone "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples" <br>
cd /Users/bweekes/workspace/gs2/java-docs-samples/speech/grpc <br>
mvn compile <br>
mvn assembly:single <br>

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/bweekes/workspace/gs/Blackboard-233316c9dd01.json

bin/speech-sample-streaming.sh --host=speech.googleapis.com --port=443 --sampling=16000
```

The following error is printed for all the samples

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.maxInboundMessageSize()I
at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:274)
at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:239)
at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:69)
at com.examples.cloud.speech.StreamingRecognizeClient.createChannel(StreamingRecognizeClient.java:109)
at com.examples.cloud.speech.StreamingRecognizeClient.main(StreamingRecognizeClient.java:287)
```

Comment: Change the pom file to use   <grpc-version>1.0.3</grpc-version>

Comment: Does changing the grpc artifacts from 1.1.2 to 1.0.3 works for you??